# Quarkus bazel unit tests

Tags: junit, quarkus, bazel

Currently, while I'm trying to setup quarkus to work with bazel, I'm getting the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to create the application model for null
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:625)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:696)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
```

Spring based unit tests works out-of-the box. Bazel test configuration

```
load("@contrib_rules_jvm//java:defs.bzl", "JUNIT5_DEPS", "java_test_suite")


java_test_suite(
    name = "test",
    srcs = [
        "DataTestIT.java",
    ],
    runner = "junit5",
    test_suffixes = [
        "Test.java",
    ],
    runtime_deps = JUNIT5_DEPS + [
        artifact("io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-core"),
        artifact("io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-bom-test"),
        artifact("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5"),
        artifact("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5-mockito"),
        artifact("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5-internal"),
    ],
    deps = [
        # internal packages
        # external deps
        artifact("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5"),
        artifact("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5-mockito"),
        artifact("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5-internal"),
        artifact("io.rest-assured:rest-assured"),
        artifact("org.skyscreamer:jsonassert"),
        artifact("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore"),
        # mandatory
        artifact("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api"),
        artifact("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params"),
        artifact("org.assertj:assertj-core"),
        artifact("org.mockito:mockito-core"),
        artifact("org.mockito:mockito-inline"),
        artifact("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter"),
    ],
)
```

I tried to investigate quarkus `QuarkusTestExtension` class code (Quarkus ver 2.16), anyway it didn't gave me an answer. Tried to play with classpath. Going to take a look at junit classpath while run using `mvn`. Seems maven/gradle is the only way, but I don't want to use this way.

Appreciate for any idea.

Thanks!

Comment: More information: `[io.qua.boo.BootstrapAppModelFactory] (main) Unable to locate the maven project on the filesystem`, the entry appeared after specifying `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager` as JVM flag

Comment: It might be worth trying with Quarkus 3.2 (or higher). In 2.16, some test-scope test framework classes wouldn't be included on the classpath in some scenarios.

Comment: Migrated to spring. It took two days anyway worth it. It's easy if you have API-first server stubs generation in bazel graph.
About Quarkus - honestly, I'll ask engineers to avoid its usage.